# Can I switch the bank account associated with my AdSense account?

Tags: google-adsense

I'm asking because I have my YouTube account tied to a family member's bank account, and I created my own bank account recently. And I wanted to switch the earnings to mine.

Answer (score 1):

In AdSense, go to the Payments tab, and choose Add Payment Method.

At one time, your bank account had to be in the same name as your AdSense account.   I don't know if this is enforced any more though.   I suspect it isn't.  But you will find out when you add your account and then AdSense verify it.